# Java Persistence API

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to [Java Persistence API](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_JPA%3F). I have just learnt it and now want to use it in my Java Desktop Application. But I have the following questions regarding it:

Q1. Which JPA implementation is smallest in size (as I want to have my application's size as small as possible)?

Q2. How to find the value of the `<provider>` tag in the `persistence.xml` file. I know that its value is vendor specific but I couldn't find the value for the JPA implementation downloaded from [here](http://findjar.com/jar/net/java/dev/glassfish/glassfish-persistence-api/b32g/glassfish-persistence-api-b32g.jar.html).

Comment: That being referred to is NOT an *implementation* of JPA. It's simply the JPA API jar (of interfaces) and is required by all implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Q1. Which JPA implementation is smallest in size (as I want to have my application's size as small as possible)?

For JPA 1.0:

- Hibernate Entity Manager 3.4.0.GA: ~4.9MB
- EclipseLink 1.1.3: ~4.7MB
- OpenJPA 1.2.2: ~2.7MB (I'm not sure for this one, not tested for now so I may be missing some jars)

I would stay away from TopLink Essentials.

For JPA 2.0:

- DataNucleus 2.0.3: ~3.7MB
- EclipseLink 1.2 and 2.0+: ~4.8MB
- Hibernate Entity Manager 3.5.0-Final: ~5.8MB
- OpenJPA 2.0.0-beta3: not measured (still in beta)

These measures have been done on my pet project (including dependencies except the JDBC driver). Personally, I wouldn't base my choice on the size only, even for a desktop app.

> Q2. How to find the value of the  tag in the persistence.xml file.

- DataNucleus: `org.datanucleus.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl`
- EclipseLink: `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider`
- Hibernate: `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence`
- OpenJPA: `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl`
- TopLink Essentials: `oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider`

Comment: Ok... which implementation would you choose regardless of the size?

Comment: I was about to go with TopLink Essentials. Why would you stay away from that?

Comment: @Yatendra Because nothing happens with Toplink Essentials (it's maintained but dead), because it requires weaving, because you need to use a javaagent, because I've always found it painful to use (might not be that painful with 5 entities though). But it works.

Comment: @Yatendra I like Hibernate which is widely used, tested, supported and this matters to me. But, again, this might not be that critical for a five tables application. Maybe you should implement your app and test it with various JPA providers.

Answer (score 2):

Q1. VERY rough calculated:

- Hibernate (versions around 3.4.0.GA) with deps is ca. 3.6 Mb.
- TopLink Essentials (2.0.1-04) ca. 2.4 Mb.
- EclipseLink (ex. TopLink) (1.1.3-M1) ca. 4.7 Mb.

Q2. Open the JAR, check the `META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` file.

Comment: The JPA imlementation (glassfish-persistence-api-b32g) whose link I have provided in my question has just 50KB size. But it hasn't any `services` folder in `META-INF` folder.

Comment: It's API, not implementation. As far as I know, GlassFish uses EclipseLink as RI.

Comment: @BalusC Would you like to comment on `<a href="http://findjar.com/jar/net/java/dev/glassfish/glassfish-persistence-api/b32g/glassfish-persistence-api-b32g.jar.html">glassfish-persistence-api-b32g</a>` JPA implementation. I have been attracted towards it due to its lowest size (50KB).

Answer (score 0):

You mean size in memory ? or size of jar ? Size in memory depends on how many classes are being persisted, the metadata for them, how many EntityManagers open, what is in the L1/L2 caches. I know that DataNucleus uses less memory than Hibernate since users themselves have reported that, no idea against the other primary implementations.

Size of a jar is a pointless measure of anything, since the majority of things there may not be in use.

PS. DataNucleus is also a JPA1+2 implementation