# How to use JDBC on Google AppEngine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, jdbc, relational-database

I have an application that is using JDBC to manipulate its data.
I'm looking for a way to run the application on Appengine. Unfortunately, it seems like there aren't many options besides datastore (which I just can't get used to).

I've tried to use an embedded JavaDB, but Appengine blocks FileOutputStream (throws an exception "java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class" on initial driver loading). Therefore, I haven't tried Sqlite.

I've also tried to use Jiql, a new project that offers a JDBC interface to Datastore. However, I just can't seem to establish a "connection". It is somewhat unclear to me how to use jiql (like: what user/pass do you supply?), despite the few examples on their site.

I've looked at Google Cloud SQL and eventually signed up for it. It seemed to be the perfect solution to our problem, until I realized it's a paid service (it'll be paid soon, once it leaves the beta phase). I prefer not to pay (yet) as I'm still testing and evaluating the potential of GAE.

--

What would you recommend, keeping in mind would like to use JDBC for the persistence layer of the application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAE supports two frameworks for persistence, JPA and JDO. There are few frameworks that plays well with GAE rules like [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). But to start with datastore you can also take at google tutorial [GAE DATASTORE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/). If you need to learn the relationship with JPA and support for JDBC persistence Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560500/hibernate-or-jpa-or-jdbc-or)

Comment: Oh, so GAE supports JPA/JDO! I might take that approach then. Currently I was developping my own layer on top of JDBC and Datastore... Thank you for the link, that's some useful information there.