# JPA - How to set string column to varchar(max) in DDL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, ddl

With [JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2560125/1429387), DDL-generation for the attribute:

```
@Column
final String someString;
```

will be `someString varchar(255) null`

```
@Column(length = 1337)
final String someString;
```

will yield `someString varchar(1337) null`.

But how can I get it to produce `someString varchar(max) null`?

Is it possible using the `length`-attribute, or do I need to use the `columnDefinition`-attribute?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Some months have passed, new knowledge acquired, so I'll answer my own question:

```
@Lob
@Column
final String someString;
```

yields the most correct result. With the version of `hbm2ddl` I'm using, this will be transformed to the type `text` with `SqlServerDialect`. Since [`varchar(max)` is the replacement for `text`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834863/1429387) in newer versions of [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), hopefully, newer versions of `hbm2ddl` will yield `varchar(max)` instead of `text` for this type of mapping (I'm stuck at a quite dated version of Hibernate at the moment..)

Comment: Providing a custom SQLServerDialect that maps a text lob to varchar(max) might also do the trick, haven't tried though.

Answer (score 0):

Since `length` is defined in the JPA spec and javadocs as `int` type and `max` is not an `int` then it's safe to assume that you're consigned to the `columnDefinition` datastore-dependent route. But then `varchar(max)` is datastore-dependent anyway.

Comment: Other places in the project large texts were annotated with `@Lob`, which results in a `text` SQL-datatype. Will do the same..

Answer (score -2):

Hi the below code fixed the same issue

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")

@Lob

final String someString;
```

Comment: This does not provide any improvement to existing answers, it has both @Lob and columnDefinition that does the same, and the use of columnDefinition unnecessarily breaks portability.

Answer (score -5):

Use `@Size(max = 1337)`. It does generate `varchar(1337)`

Comment: @aycanadal, just in case you did not find the answer, check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588354/difference-between-size-length-and-columnlength-value-when-using-jpa-and-h/34589474#34589474

Comment: I did not downvote, but I know why.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   varchar(max) .. "max" is not a placeholder for a number (where you have 1337)  .. varchar(max) (no substitutions) is a datatype in sql server.

Answer (score -5):

You Can Use this Code -

Model Code:

```
@NotNull  
@Length(max = 7)  
@Column(name = "Gender")  
private String gender;
```

SQL Output is like-

```
> gender varchar(7)
```

Comment: You are not answering the question, just repeating parts of it.