# Difference between @Size, @Length and @Column(length=value) when using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa, orm

What is the difference between the validation check of the following three fields?

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Column(name = "MY_FIELD_1", length=13)
    private String myField1;
    @Column(name = "MY_FIELD_2")
    @Size(min = 13, max = 13)
    private String myField2;
    @Column(name = "MY_FIELD_3")
    @Length(min = 13, max = 13)
    private String myField3;

    // getter & setter

}
```

I read that the first one has to do with DDL stuff.
The second is for bean-validation.
The third is for hibernate-validation.

Is that correct? What I still don't understand is: When do I have to use which one? When does one of these annotations trigger?

Edit: Think of the following situation:
Given the requirement to develope an entity with a field of type string with length 13. Which of above mentioned methods would you choose? Or even better: Which questions do you have to ask yourself to find out which one suits your purposes?

Comment: Column is nothing to do with VALIDATION. Size is JPA standard. Length is proprietary. The answer should be clear from that ... @Size

Comment: Length is proprietary? So I am not allowed to use this in general?

Comment: As the answer says, it is a Hibernate-specific vendor extension. Makes no sense to use it (apart from people who would want to tie themselves to one JPA implementation for no reason)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

1. [`@Column`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html) is a JPA annotation and the `length` attribute is used by the schema generation tool to set the associated SQL column length.
2. [`@Size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) is a Bean Validation annotation that validates that the associated String has a value whose length is bounded by the minimum and maximum values.
3. [`@Length`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.List.html) is a Hibernate-specific annotation and has the same meaning as `@Size`

So both `2.` and `3.` should validate the `String` length using Bean Validation. I'd pick `2.` because it's generic.

Comment: I am using no hbm-mapping files, so 1 is not suitable for me, right? When do I use Size over Length, or do I even use both?

Comment: `@Size` is universal, being defined by JPA. `@Length` is only available for Hibernate.

Comment: `@Size` is __not__ a JPA annotation at all. It is a Bean Validation API annotation! also would be better to say `@Column` is a JPA annotation for use by the JPA provider in schema generation (only), since that is usable by all JPA providers.

Comment: Is there an annotation that does both? or if I want both bean validation AND DDL Specification, do I have to use both annotations (@Size and @Column) ?