# Validation on enum in spring request

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, enums

I have a request `WorkerRequest` in which there is an `enum` which has `FULL_TIME`, `MANAGER` and so on.

In `WorkerRequest` how can I apply the length validation on this enum?

Example: enum type should not be greater than 8 characters.

`FULL_TIME` valid (8 characters)

`PERMANENT` invalid (9 characters)

Currently if I put `javax.validation.constraints.Size`

```
  @Size(min = 0, max = 8, message = "Allowed length for workerType is 8.")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private WorkerType workerType;
```

it throws an error :

> HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint
>   'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type
>   'com.XX.XX.XX.WorkerType'.
>   Check configuration for 'workerType'

Comment: create your own validation, and check the size, not of the enum_type, but of enum_type.name();

Comment: Currently`enum_type.name()` would have for both constants the same length of 9 characters. Instead of renaming the constants to match a desired length it would be better e.g. to override `toString()` and to check its length or to introduce a dedicated method.

Comment: @LuCio depends. It's easy enough, once it's a String, to filter out underscores and other chars you don't want to take into account.

Comment: @Stultuske Ok . if you just want to filter the enum at a certain place and don't want to define this in the enum, then this is the way to go.

Comment: chances are, in some places you don't want that validation, or you want the validation to behave differently. the enum itself shouldn't know about the validation. for instance, if you would have an enum that on MY_ENUM.isValid() would return false .... why would you even have that enum to begin with?

Comment: Why do you want to validate the length? the enum can only handle the values that are part of the enum, anything else will fail to bind/convert. Also `FULL_TIME` is 9 chars not 8!.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's 9 chars, but 8 letters. It depends on how you look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [Difference between @Size, @Length and @Column(length=value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588354/difference-between-size-length-and-columnlength-value)

> **@Size** is a Bean Validation annotation that validates that the
>   associated **String** has a value whose length is bounded by the minimum
>   and maximum values.

You can only specify the the maximum required length for persisting enum value in your db. For example, if you define `@Column(length = 8)` instead of @Size you will see `workerType VARCHAR(8)` in your db definition correspondingly.

But there is a workaround for it: 
suppose you have

```
 public enum WorkerType {PERMANENT , FULL_TIME, ...};
```

1. **Define a custom validation annotation:**

   ```
   @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Constraint(validatedBy = EnumSizeLimit.class)
   public @interface EnumSizeLimit {
       String message() default "{com.example.app.EnumSizeLimit.message}";
       Class<?>[] groups() default {};
       Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
       Class<? extends Enum<?>> targetClassType();
   }
   ```
2. **Implement a Validator:**

   ```
   public class EnumSizeLimitValidator implements ConstraintValidator < EnumSizeLimit , String > {
        private Set < String > allowedValues;

        @SuppressWarnings({
            "unchecked",
            "rawtypes"
        })
       @Override
       public void initialize(EnumSizeLimit targetEnum) {
       Class << ? extends Enum > enumSelected = targetEnum.targetClassType();
       allowedValues = (Set < String > ) EnumSet.allOf(enumSelected).stream().map(e - > ((Enum << ? extends Enum << ? >> ) e).name())
           .collect(Collectors.toSet());
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
           return value == null || (value.length>=0 && value.length<=8)) ? true : false;
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Define Field:**

   ```
   @EnumSizeLimit (targetClassType = WorkerType.class, message = "your message" 
   private String workerType;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the need of size validation. The fact of using enum in the request will oblige the serialization to map the value to one of the enum possible values. In case you fill the string json with "invalid" as worker type, spring will throw:

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `WorkerType` from String "invalid": value not one of declared Enum instance names: etc.

You can catch the exception in a custom rest exception handler